# xpdf (pdftotext) with language pack call from different directory

Tags: macos, terminal, pdftotext, xpdf

I am experimenting with xpdf (pdftotext) on a macOS Terminal. I use one language package (Japanese). Everything works fine if I call the executable like this (from the lib directory):

```
lib kelly$ ./p2t -enc UTF-8 jp.pdf
```

and my data structure

```
files/lib/pdftotext
files/lib/xpdfrc
files/lib/jp.pdf #file to convert
files/options/Enc/jp/ # Here I have the language package files
```

and the following edited xpdfrc configuration file:

```
#----- begin Japanese support package (2011-sep-02)
cidToUnicode    Adobe-Japan1    ../options/Enc/jp/Adobe-Japan1.cidToUnicode
unicodeMap  ISO-2022-JP ../options/Enc/jp/ISO-2022-JP.unicodeMap
unicodeMap  EUC-JP      ../options/Enc/jp/EUC-JP.unicodeMap
unicodeMap  Shift-JIS   ../options/Enc/jp/Shift-JIS.unicodeMap
cMapDir     Adobe-Japan1    ../options/Enc/jp/CMap
toUnicodeDir            ../options/Enc/jp/CMap
#----- end Japanese support package
```

the problem I have is to call 'pdftoext' from a different directory, for example from 'files'. In this case, the files that the configuration files is pointing to are not seen.

```
files kelly$ ./lib/p2t -enc UTF-8 ./lib/jp.pdf
```

I get the following error:

```
Syntax Error: Unknown character collection 'Adobe-Japan1'
```

And the generated file is garbage.

Any idea on how the configuration file needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve a similar problem.
I installed pdftotext with a brew cask.

The installation was done with the following command

```
$ brew cask install pdftotext
$ pdftotext -v
pdftotext version 3.03
Copyright 1996-2011 Glyph & Cog, LLC
```

and place the xpdfrc/language support packages in the following directory I did.

```
ls /usr/local/etc/xpdfrc
/usr/local/etc/xpdfrc
```

I downloaded the Japanese Language Pack from here.
https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html

```
$ tree /usr/local/share/xpdf
/usr/local/share/xpdf
└── japanese
    ├── Adobe-Japan1.cidToUnicode
    ├── CMap
    │   ├── 78-EUC-H
    │   ├── 78-EUC-V
    │   ├── 78-H
    │   ├── 78-RKSJ-H
    │   ├── 78-RKSJ-V
    │   ├── 78-V
    │   ├── 78ms-RKSJ-H
    │   ├── 78ms-RKSJ-V
    │   ├── 83pv-RKSJ-H
    │   ├── 90ms-RKSJ-H
    │   ├── 90ms-RKSJ-UCS2
    │   ├── 90ms-RKSJ-V
    │   ├── 90msp-RKSJ-H
    │   ├── 90msp-RKSJ-V
    │   ├── 90pv-RKSJ-H
    │   ├── 90pv-RKSJ-UCS2
    │   ├── 90pv-RKSJ-UCS2C
    │   ├── 90pv-RKSJ-V
    │   ├── Add-H
    │   ├── Add-RKSJ-H
    │   ├── Add-RKSJ-V
    │   ├── Add-V
    │   ├── Adobe-Japan1-0
    │   ├── Adobe-Japan1-1
    │   ├── Adobe-Japan1-2
    │   ├── Adobe-Japan1-3
    │   ├── Adobe-Japan1-4
    │   ├── Adobe-Japan1-5
    │   ├── Adobe-Japan1-6
    │   ├── Adobe-Japan1-UCS2
    │   ├── EUC-H
    │   ├── EUC-V
    │   ├── Ext-H
    │   ├── Ext-RKSJ-H
    │   ├── Ext-RKSJ-V
    │   ├── Ext-V
    │   ├── H
    │   ├── Hankaku
    │   ├── Hiragana
    │   ├── Katakana
    │   ├── NWP-H
    │   ├── NWP-V
    │   ├── RKSJ-H
    │   ├── RKSJ-V
    │   ├── Roman
    │   ├── UniJIS-UCS2-H
    │   ├── UniJIS-UCS2-HW-H
    │   ├── UniJIS-UCS2-HW-V
    │   ├── UniJIS-UCS2-V
    │   ├── UniJIS-UTF16-H
    │   ├── UniJIS-UTF16-V
    │   ├── UniJIS-UTF32-H
    │   ├── UniJIS-UTF32-V
    │   ├── UniJIS-UTF8-H
    │   ├── UniJIS-UTF8-V
    │   ├── UniJIS2004-UTF16-H
    │   ├── UniJIS2004-UTF16-V
    │   ├── UniJIS2004-UTF32-H
    │   ├── UniJIS2004-UTF32-V
    │   ├── UniJIS2004-UTF8-H
    │   ├── UniJIS2004-UTF8-V
    │   ├── UniJISPro-UCS2-HW-V
    │   ├── UniJISPro-UCS2-V
    │   ├── UniJISPro-UTF8-V
    │   ├── UniJISX0213-UTF32-H
    │   ├── UniJISX0213-UTF32-V
    │   ├── UniJISX02132004-UTF32-H
    │   ├── UniJISX02132004-UTF32-V
    │   ├── V
    │   └── WP-Symbol
    ├── EUC-JP.unicodeMap
    ├── ISO-2022-JP.unicodeMap
    ├── README
    ├── Shift-JIS.unicodeMap
    └── add-to-xpdfrc

2 directories, 76 files
```

The contents of xpdfrc are as follows

```
$ cat /usr/local/etc/xpdfrc
cidToUnicode    Adobe-Japan1    /usr/local/share/xpdf/japanese/Adobe-Japan1.cidToUnicode
unicodeMap  ISO-2022-JP /usr/local/share/xpdf/japanese/ISO-2022-JP.unicodeMap
unicodeMap  EUC-JP      /usr/local/share/xpdf/japanese/EUC-JP.unicodeMap
unicodeMap  Shift-JIS   /usr/local/share/xpdf/japanese/Shift-JIS.unicodeMap
cMapDir     Adobe-Japan1    /usr/local/share/xpdf/japanese/CMap
toUnicodeDir            /usr/local/share/xpdf/japanese/CMap
```